# Import Cartesian coordinates from Excel and count its area

Tags: python, coordinates, area, excel

I'm new and struggling with calculating xy area from Excel data ( or it can be any type of data with xy coordinates). Moreover according to task it must use all existing coordinates in Excel file.

[image: How coordinates looks like]

My code

```
import openpyxl


book = openpyxl.load_workbook('coordinates.xlsx')
sheet = book.active

for row_i in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    x = sheet.cell(row=row_i, column=1).value
    y = sheet.cell(row=row_i, column=2).value
polygon = [[x,y]]
print(polygon)
area = 0.0
n = len(polygon)
for i in range(n):
    i1 = (i+1)%n
    area += polygon[i][0]*polygon[i1][1] - polygon[i1][0]*polygon[i][1]
area *= 0.5
print('area = ', area)
```

I don't know how to make that polygon = [[x,y]] would be like polygon [[608....,5105...],[6085.....,517...]], my code only picks last row data, I need that it pick all data and use it to calculate. Or if you have better idea, please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is picking the last because you are not appending to the array. Check below code:

```
import openpyxl


book = openpyxl.load_workbook('coordinates.xlsx')
sheet = book.active
polygon = []

for row_i in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    x = sheet.cell(row=row_i, column=1).value
    y = sheet.cell(row=row_i, column=2).value
    polygon.append([x,y])

print(polygon)
area = 0.0
n = len(polygon)
for i in range(n):
    i1 = (i+1)%n
    area += polygon[i][0]*polygon[i1][1] - polygon[i1][0]*polygon[i][1]
area *= 0.5
print('area = ', area)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the `arcpy` python module you can solve this by creating an `arcpy.Array` object of your coordinates. You would then use this as an input to create an `arcpy.Polygon` object. To get the area of the `Polygon` object you then use the call `.area` on your `Polygon` object to get the area.

If I understand your question correctly, the basic workflow would be:

1. Loop over coordinates and add them to your `Array`
2. Once all coordinates have been loaded to the `Array` use this as input to create a `Polygon` object
3. Call `.area` on the `Polygon` object to get the area of the polygon

I can provide more specific code examples if needed. More information can be found about the `arcpy.Polygon` object [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/polygon.htm). Additionally, this same workflow could be accomplished using the python packages of gdal.